# Unable to switch window in fantoccini

Tags: rust, automated-tests

I have opened a page https://www.jiocloud.com and trying to automate to login.

```
client.goto("https://www.jiocloud.com/").await?;
// jio click on login.
let ele = client
    .wait()
    .for_element(Locator::Css(r#"button.btn-login"#))
    .await?;
ele.click().await?;
// jio-sign in with google.
let ele = client
    .wait()
    .for_element(Locator::Css(r#"button.social-btn.btn-google"#))
    .await?;
ele.click().await?;

// this sleep was required otherwise windows() returns only one window.
std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_millis(1000));

let windows = client.windows().await?; // ex: returns vec[window1, window2]

let mut next = client.windows().await?.remove(1);
println!("switch to >> {:?}", next); // ex: switch to >> window2
client.switch_to_window(next);

// still shows me previous window as active.
println!("we are in {:?}", client.window().await?); // ex: window1
```

Answer (score 0):

I was not waiting for an async call `client.switch_to_window(next);`